# proving a modular arithmetic and using the fact to compute

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

So i was given this question

Show that for any natural n

$10^n(mod11)$ $=$ $ \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             1,  & \mbox{ n even}\\
             \\ 10, &\mbox{ n odd} \\
             \\ 
             \end{array}
   \right.$

Using this fact compute $654321 (mod 11)$

My problem is im used to just solving the modular arithmetic not proving. Like i know $654321 (mod 11)$ = $8$, but how would i prove the fact and use it?

Answer (score 0):

$$10 \equiv 10 \mod{11}$$
$$10^2 \equiv 10 \cdot 10 \equiv 1 \mod{11}$$
$$10^3 \equiv 1 \cdot 10 \equiv 10 \mod{11}$$
$$\vdots$$

Answer (score 0):

$10^n \equiv (-1)^n \pmod{11}$.